# Python int function

Tags: python, function, integer

Can anyone please tell me what are the inner workings of int function.
I know that it converts stuff into an integer but i want to know HOW it converts the stuff, like what are the inner workings of the function

Comment: To start, `int` is not a function; it's a type. You are basically asking how a given Python implementation defines that type, which means looking at the source code.

Comment: @chepner: The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html) does say `int()` is a function, so I think some confusion *is* understandable.

Comment: Infinite: what don't you understand about what's in the documentation for the [`int()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#int) function?